# Function to mask everything but last four digits of SSN

Tags: vb.net

I have this function for ID. I need new function to mask first 5 characters something like "xxx-xx-1234"

```
public shared function ID (ByVal id As string) As string
    if string.IsnullorEmpty(id) then
        return string.empty
    elseif isnumeric(id) then
        return string.Format("{0:000-00-0000}", CDbl(id))
    elseif id.length=9 then
        return id.Substring(0,3) & "-" & _
               id.Substring(3,2) & "-" & _
               id.Substring(5,4) 
    else
        return id
        End if
        End function
```

Comment: I think string.Format("{0:XXX-XX-0000}", CDbl(id)) should do what your after

Comment: @Hursey so, just replace `string.Format("{0:000-00-0000}", CDbl(id))` with `string.Format("{0:XXX-XX-0000}", CDbl(id))` and keep rest of the function as it is ?